# Spring-Data-Rest Flatten Object hierarchy when serializing to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

We are working in a project with spring-data-rest 2.4.2.RELEASE (with spring-boot, JPA/Hibernate).
We have a database model with this structure:

```
table A:
  name: string
  b -> B //meaning a reference to table B
table B:
  x: number
  y: number
```

We need to expose entity A this using REST/JSON as:

```html
{ "name": "myName", "position": {"x": 1, "y": 3}}
```

We already have a java class for Position:

```java
public class Position {

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty
    private Float x;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty
    private Float y;
}
```

So we create our A and B classes mapped to the database tables using JPA annotations, but we expose a property `position` in A annotating with `@JsonProperty` a getter that access directly to B:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @JsonProperty
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private B b;

  @JsonProperty
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty
  public Position getPosition() {
      if (b == null) {
          b = new B();
      }
      return b.getPosition();
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public void setPosition(Position position) {
      if (this.b == null) {
          this.b = new B();
      }  
      this.b.setPosition(position);
  }
}
```

And my B object, which I don't want to expose in the REST API:

```java
@Entity
public class B {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @JsonProperty
  private Long id;

  @Embedded
  @Column(nullable = true)
  private Position position;

  Position getPosition() {
      return position;
  }

  void setPosition(Position position) {
      this.position = position;
  }

}
```

With this structure I can POST new objects to my API without problems:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json' localhost:12000/as -d '
{ "name": "aName", "position": {"x":1, "y":2}}'
```

This creates an object:

```
{
  "name" : "aName",
  "position" : {
    "x" : 1.0,
    "y" : 2.0
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:12000/as/5"
    },
    "a" : {
      "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:12000/as/5"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to update the object with a PUT:

```
curl -XPUT -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json' localhost:12000/as/5 -d '
{"name": "aName", "position": {"x":4, "y":3}}'
```

I get this error

> {"cause":{"cause":{"cause":null,"message":null},"message":"Could not read payload!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"},"message":"Could not read an object of type class io.epiclabs.flex.network.A from the request!; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read payload!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"

Debugging into spring-data-rest code, I found that the problem is in `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.DomainObjectReader.doMerge`  line 192.

```
PersistentProperty<?> property = mappedProperties.getPersistentProperty(fieldName);

if (associationLinks.isLinkableAssociation(property)) {
        continue;
}

PersistentPropertyAccessor accessor = entity.getPropertyAccessor(target);
Object nested = accessor.getProperty(property);
```

`property` is null because there is no mapping information for `position` in A object (mappedProperties are taken only from JPA mapping information).

It seems that it is only doing that for updates (PUT) and in POST it is just taking POJO and Jackson mapping information for setting Position object.

My question is: How can we configure our mapping so the Jackson modules takes information from JSONProperties annotations instead for JPA entity information when serializing/deserializing?

Can we do this json mapping in a different way without changing our database model?

Comment: Assuming your data model is supposed to be exactly what it is, I'd recommand you to write custom serializer/deserializer for your A entity. That way you have full control over how jackson does serialize/deserialize your objects and can get rid of the annotation mess, you currently have...